# Thermal expansion of metal spring

Tags: thermodynamics

I am attempting to figure out why a laser layout tool I have is drifting over time. It was designed with a small adjustment mechanism that relies on a spring to apply pressure to a fulcrum that rotates the entire laser. A screw is used to apply and release pressure on the spring thus moving the laser very small amounts left and right.

I am getting a drift in the lasers horizontal position of about 1/2inch at 100 feet over the course of several hours. I am doing this test at night and there is about a 15 degree Fahrenheit temperature from when I start the test to when it is complete.

I made a Sketch-Up model of the device and determined that 5 micron change in position (at the end of the fulcrum) is all it would take to move the laser 1/2 inch at 100ft.

My question is it possible that my spring is expanding and contracting 5 microns with a 15 degree temperature change?

I am not an engineer and am looking for some speculation just to rule in or rule out the general possibility.

The spring looks similar [to this spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgCQj.jpg).

The diameter of the entire spring is about 1/4 inch. The diameter of the coiled metal wire is about 1/6 inch. The spring length is about 1/2" uncompressed. It consists of about 8 loops.

I do not know the metal it is made of, speculation on different scenarios would be helpful as, again, I'm just trying to rule in or out the possibility.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linear expansion coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion#Linear_expansion) of a material $\alpha_L$ gives the change in the length $\Delta L$ of a bar of that material after a change in temperature $\Delta T$ given the original length of the bar $L$:

$$\Delta L= L\ \alpha_L \Delta T $$

Modeling your spring as a 2 cm long steel bar and using [steel's $\alpha_L$ of $1.2 \times 10^{-5}$ (m/m°C)](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-thermal-expansion-d_1379.html) with a temperature difference of 8.3 °C (15 degrees Fahrenheit difference) gives $\Delta L = 2\ \mu m$.